# Internet Exporer Input Button - on click it seems to add a shadow and makes the text grey

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, input

I've got a weird problem in internet expolorer.

I'm styling an input button. This is what I've come up with in my CSS.

```
.gform_wrapper input.gform_button {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #045d8e;
    padding: 2px 10px 0; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    height: 35px;
    width: auto !important;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

#ie7 .gform_wrapper input.gform_button {
    width: 90px;
    padding: 1px 0 0;
}

.gform_wrapper input.gform_button:hover {
    background: #024061 !important;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.gform_wrapper input.gform_button:active,
.gform_wrapper input.gform_button:focus {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: #024061 !important;
}
```

All these styles seem to be working but in IE when you click on the button, while the form loads it adds grey colour to the text and a white shadow appears. It's so weird because IE does not support text shadow.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but in my case it was a span element that was showing grey text with a white shadow after my script ran. It turned out that in internet explorer, if you set the 'disabled' property of the span or div element to true, this will happen.